# Creating Multiple Threaded Loops

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

Sorry if this a bit of a basic question but I've been thinking about doing multiple sprite loops and for the first time I tried to create two  threads in main, both with while(true) loops. My intention: to have two threads looping simultaneously. However when I run the program it seems to interrupt the flow of execution and the second loop doesn't getting executed in a new thread but just stops with the program stuck on the first endless while() loop of a thread. I think it is still just executing the main thread rather than starting a new one and then continuing on.

I've tried it two ways:

Once with Threads:

```
public class Zzz {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        r1 r = new r1();
        r2 a = new r2();
        r.start();
        a.start();
    }
}

public class r1 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("r1");
            try {
                this.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }

}

public class r2 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("r2");
                        try {
                this.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

**And once with Runnable:**

```
public class Zzz {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        r1 r = new r1();
        r2 a = new r2();
        r.run();
        a.run();
    }
}

public class r1 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("r1");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }

}

public class r2 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("r2");
                        try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

But to no avail. It always gets stuck at R1. Any ideas anyone? I've googled and looked around about threads and I can't find this covered anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override run method & in case of runnable you need to create instance of Thread

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("My Thread running");
        }

}
```

ánd for the case of `Runnable`

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

             public void run(){
                         System.out.println("I am executing by Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
             }
 }
```

and

```
  Thread mythread = new MyThread();
  mythread.setName("T1");
  Thread myrunnable = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
  myrunnable.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

To start threads, you need to create two `Thread`s from the `Runnable`s and start them:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
Thread t2 = new Thread(a);
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Define classes r1 and r2 as :

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("r1");
    try {
       this.sleep(100);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }        
 }

}

public class Thread2 extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("r2");
    try {
      this.sleep(100);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
}


public class ThreadTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread1 r = new Thread1();
        Thread2 a = new Thread2();
        r.start();
        a.start();
    }
}
```

Using Runnable :

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
    }

}
```

check [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) for more info